# Question on $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof for $\lim_{x \to 0} x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I'm trying to understand the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof for
$$\lim_{x \to 0} x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=0$$

We have to find $\varepsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that
$$
\left|x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right| < \varepsilon \tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$
and
$$
|x|<\delta \tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$

My work:

We know
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right| &\leq 1 \\
\implies \left|x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right| &\leq |x^2| \\
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\therefore \text{ } \left|x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right| < \delta^2 \tag{3}\label{eq3}
$$

For $0<\delta<1$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\delta^2 &< \delta \\
\implies \left|x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right| &< \delta
\end{aligned}
$$
and hence we can choose any $\delta$, such that $0 < \delta \leq \varepsilon$. So far so good.

But, for $\delta \geq 1$, we have
$$
\delta^2 \geq \delta
$$
The range of value for $\delta$ in this case that I can think of such that $\eqref{eq1}$ and $\eqref{eq3}$ could be reconciled is
$$
\left|x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right| < \delta \leq \varepsilon
$$

But when I check on a graphing tool, regardless of whether $\delta$ is $<1$ or $\geq 1$, $0<\delta\leq\varepsilon$ holds.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT:**

Since $0<\delta\leq\varepsilon$ and from $\eqref{eq2}$, we get
$$
|x|<\delta \leq\varepsilon
\implies |x|^2 < \delta^2 \leq \varepsilon^2
$$

So, since
$$
\left|x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right| \leq |x^2| \\
\implies \left|x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right| < \delta ^2 \leq \varepsilon^2
$$

So, can we now say $\delta \leq \varepsilon$, regardless of values that either take?

Comment: Recall that $\delta$ MAY depend on $\varepsilon$. So GIVEN $\varepsilon>0$, just take $\delta=\sqrt{\varepsilon}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, and there are several ways to finish up. One thing you could do is what @Tito Eliatron suggests in his comment (this might be the most elegant way):

Let $\epsilon > 0$, set $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon}$. Then, for $|x|<\delta$ we have

\begin{equation}
\left|x^2 \sin{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\right| \leq |x|^2 < \delta^2 = \sqrt{\epsilon}^2 = \epsilon.
\end{equation}

But there is another way to "fix" your argument. As you have noted, if $\epsilon \leq 1$, you can choose $\delta = \epsilon$ and use the fact that in this case we have $\delta^2 \leq \delta$, and do the same thing as above. Then we deal with the case $\epsilon > 1$ separately. In this case, we can choose $\delta = 1$, and we have for $|x| < \delta:$

\begin{equation}
\left|x^2 \sin{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\right| \leq |x|^2 < \delta^2 = 1^2 = 1 < \epsilon.
\end{equation}

Thus, we can set $\delta = \min{(\epsilon, 1)}$ and obtain the same result. I think Tito's suggestion is more beautiful since it avoids different cases, but both methods are valid.

Answer (score 1):

In $\DeclareMathOperator{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs, $\delta$ is allowed to depend on $\epsilon$, but not vice versa. In your example, if $\epsilon\le1$, then we can set $\delta=\epsilon$, and things work out nicely. Often, weird things can happen for large values of $\epsilon$, and so as a kind of 'safety-net' we require that $\delta$ be *at most* a specific number. Here, we can set
$$
\delta=\min\left(\epsilon,1\right)
$$
and things work out nicely. It also helps to work backwards. We need
$$
\left|x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|<\epsilon
$$
or
$$
\left|x^2\right|\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|<\epsilon \, .
$$
Now, if we can make $|x^2|$ be smaller than $\epsilon$, then it will be certainly be the case that $|x^2|\left|\sin(1/x)\right|$ will be smaller than $\epsilon$, as $|\sin(1/x)|\le1$. Moreover, if $|x|<1$, then $|x^2|<|x|$. So if $|x|<\epsilon$ and $|x|<1$, then $|x^2|<|x|<\epsilon$, which is what we need. So let $\delta=\min(\epsilon,1)$, which guarantees that $|x|<1$ and $|x|<\epsilon$.